# weird error using sqlsrv in php where $_POST works and $_GET doesn't

Tags: php, forms, post, get, sqlsrv

I have little php script where using POST method works and GET doesn't.

php file #1 (relevant parts only):

```
    echo "<form method='get' action=" . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . ">
    <input type='text' name='date' placeholder='yyyy-mm-dd'>
    <input type='submit' name='submit'>
  </form>";

if (!empty($_GET['submit'])) {
  $date = $_GET['date'];

  $sql = "select COUNT(cTriggerName) as Darab, cState as Status, right(cTriggerName,2) as DepotCode
  from BNDOCEX2TLOG
  where
  StartTime > ? and
  StartTime < dateadd(d,1,?)
  group by right(cTriggerName,2) , cState";

  $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, array($date, $date));

  if ($stmt === false) {
  die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
  }

  $_SESSION['result'] = $stmt;
}
```

php file #2 (relevant parts only):

```
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($_SESSION['result'], SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>".$row['Darab']."</td><td>".$row['Status']."</td><td>".$row['DepotCode']."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
```

When I use the `post` method in the form and `$_POST['submit']` and `$_POST['date']` everything works but when I use the `get` method in the form and `$_GET['submit']` and `$_GET['date']` I get the following fatal error:

sqlsrv_fetch_array(): 9 is not a valid ss_sqlsrv_stmt resourceenter code here

I have checked the value of the `$date` variable with both `var_dump()` and `print_r()` and they are exactly the same both when using get or post (eg. 2015-04-20 as a string). I can't think of a reason why this wouldn't work with get.

Comment: "weird error using sqlsrv in php where $_GET works and $_GET doesn't", Typo in the subject ?

Comment: sorry, typo corrected

Comment: You're having multiple '?' in the $sql, shouldn't they be replaced with some values by bind_param and using prepare ? Maybe out of context question. And is the the EXACT same code working with POST but not with GET ?

Comment: Yes, I could use that but since this is just for anti-injection sqlsrv_query is enough for me and I have tested it for about the 10th time and it is not working when using GET with the exact same code. If anyone could suggest ways I could debug this, I would be thankful.

Comment: Testing it further, it seems that the $stmt is not getting through  $_SESSION['result'] when using get but I can't figure out why. parameters in the url shouldn't affect the current session, right?

Comment: No the url aren't doing anything to the session.